# Doctrine Inheritance: get the child class in result array

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm using Doctrine2 with Symfony2.
I have an abstract Entity `Vehicle` which has child Entities `Car`, `Boat` and `Aircraft`.

I use the following request:

```
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();

    $qb->select('v.id', 'v.name', 'v.color');
    $qb->from('MyBundle:Vehicle','v');

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Which gives me an array like this:

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'id' => 1
      'name' => 'Car#1'
      'color' => 'blue'           
  1 => 
    array
      'id' => 2
      'name' => 'SuperTanker'
      'color' => 'yellow'
  2 => 
    array
      'id' => 3
      'name' => 'Boeing 747'
      'color' => 'white'
```

**What I need is** to add in the result array the information about the class name of each element (it could be the content of the discriminator column, too). 
It would give something like:

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'type' => 'Car'  // <-- NEW
      'id' => 1
      'name' => 'Car#1'
      'color' => 'blue'           
  1 => 
    array
      'type' => 'Boat'  // <-- NEW
      'id' => 2
      'name' => 'SuperTanker'
      'color' => 'yellow'
  2 => 
    array
      'type' => 'Aircraft'  // <-- NEW
      'id' => 3
      'name' => 'Boeing 747'
      'color' => 'white'
```

Note: I know that I can get that by getting the full `Vehicle` objects instead of an array (`$qb->select('v');`) and then test each object to know if they are `instance of` something ; or I could use `get_class($vehicle);` but I need that my request returns an array (my `Vehicle` object is quite big and in this case I need to access only few attributes on many `Vehicle`).

Comment: What about partial selects? You can still select few columns and get result formatted as objects. More info - http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/partial-objects.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I beleive that is not possible, at least not out of box.

However, **jasonhofer** on GitHub wrote a `TYPE()` function which does exactly that. Take a look:

**[jasonhofer / doctrine-dql-type-function.php](https://gist.github.com/jasonhofer/8420677)**

With this function it would be possible to execute something like this:

```
$qb->select('v.id', 'v.name', 'v.color', 'TYPE(v)');
```

Haven't tested this code but it seems valid.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the info, it seems to be the answer to my question. "Seems", because I didn't test the code either. I refactored my code a bit and I was then smarter to do as many request as there are children.